# Checking if a tree is balanced or not

Tags: java, tree

I was writing this code to check if a tree is balanced or not and I ran into a situation where I would have liked the method to return 2 values at each step. First to signify whether the tree is balanced at that level or not, and second to return the height at the level so that I can use it to check the balanced nature of the parent. I ended up writing the method such that it returns -1 if the tree is not balanced and the actual height if the tree is balanced at that level.

Is there a better way to do it? If not, then I think I should at least have a better name for the method `getHeight`. Can you review my code as a whole and let me know my shortcomings?

```
public boolean isBalanced(Node root){
        return getHeight(root)!=-1;
    }

private int getHeight(Node node){
    if(node ==null)
        return 1;

    int leftHeight = getHeight(node.getLeft());
    int rightHeight = getHeight(node.getRight());
    if(leftHeight==-1 || rightHeight ==-1)
        return -1;

    int diff = Math.abs(leftHeight-rightHeight);
    if(diff>1)
        return -1;

    return Math.max(leftHeight,rightHeight) + 1;

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8015630/definition-of-a-balanced-tree Is this your assumption of a balanced tree?

Comment: Yeah. A tree is balanced if leftSubTree is balanced, rightSubTree is balanced and the difference in height between the left and right subtree is at most 1.

Comment: but each subTree should also be balanced.  Do I understand the code not right or don't you check that?

Comment: @chillworld If a subtree is imbalanced, then its height will be reported as -1. There are special-case checks for that.

Comment: @200_success Oke, thx. Have a hard time with this code to see it without coding it. (Think the recursion is killing me here)

Comment: As for naming, I would name the function `getHeightIfBalanced`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These functions can be static, and therefore should be.  Marking them `static` makes it clear that this is not object-oriented code.  It also serves as a hint for the JIT to inline the helper function.

Instead of using `Math.abs()` and `Math.max()`, I suggest using `Math.max()` and `Math.min()`, which simplifies the conditionals a bit.

I would expect `getHeight(null)` to return 0.  As you've written it, a node with no children is at height 2, which is a weird place to start counting, even if it works.

Never omit braces like that.  You *will* contribute to a coding accident: [[Citation 1]](http://genius.it/5104550/ejohn.org/files/jquery-original.html) [[Citation 2]](https://www.imperialviolet.org/2014/02/22/applebug.html). If you really want to omit braces, then put the entire conditional statement on the same line for safety.

```
private static int getHeight(Node node) {
    if (node == null) return 0;

    int leftHeight  = getHeight(node.getLeft()),
        rightHeight = getHeight(node.getRight());

    int taller  = Math.max(leftHeight, rightHeight),
        shorter = Math.min(leftHeight, rightHeight);

    if (shorter < 0 || taller - shorter > 1) {
        return -1;           // Unbalanced tree
    } else {
        return taller + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you give reason why if the function can be static, it should be? i agree that for node == null the return shoul be zero

Comment: I think you cannot omit the `Math` functions in that way, because the OP code assumes that the node is balanced only if the difference between left side and right side is greater than 1 (not equal to 0), therefore your code would skip this one case i think and return -1

Comment: @Zavael Oops, I was thinking of full trees, not balanced trees. Thanks!

Comment: @Zavael `static` makes it clear that it's a pure function that has nothing to do with the state of the object — it won't be affected by it, and won't alter it. `static` also serves as a hint for the JIT to inline the function.

Comment: yes, and therefore static has nothing in common with OOP, but with procedural programming, it just extracts and moves the code to another class, it does not decouple problem into objects whit their states and behaviours. It shoul be not ecplicitly suggested to replace it with static function. I dont agree that it has nothing to do with the state of object, it shows the state of object. Its out of scope of the OP question, but to backup my thoughts, if you have time please visit http://www.yegor256.com/2015/02/26/composable-decorators.html with the video to see what i mean

Comment: I agree with most of what you say. But writing it in the way that i did using abs function adds more legibility to the code and is very close to the actual pseudo code definition of balanced tree. Looking at that code clearly tells the pseudo logic used. Don't you think?

  PS:- Love the way you break the initialization of two variables over two lines like that. I am gonna copy it from now on :)

Comment: `taller - shorter > 1` is an equally valid formulation of the algorithm, and at least as legible, in my opinion.

Comment: Yeah i suppose that is true too. 

Is this the best possible way to return 2 different kinds values from a method? If it is, then can you or @Zavael suggest a better name for the method getHeight? Because as you pointed it, it does not really always return the height. I have been thinking and the best i can come up with is getHeightIfBalanced.

Comment: If you want a "side-channel" return value, then you might look at throwing an exception — but I don't think it's the right thing to do here. Returning -1 is not that bad. `String.indexOf(…)` does something similar when the search string is not found. I recommend mentioning it in JavaDoc.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont reuse the `getHeight(Node node)` method for calculating the height, yes, you should rename it as it does not return the height for unbalanced tree and therefore the behaviour is unexpected. I would rename it to `getBalancedHeight(Node node)` for example.

After renaming you can even make the method public - it reports the state of the tree - its balanced height.

As was suggested by 200_success, fore `node == null` you should return 0 as height, as it makes more sense.

Otherwise the code looks good.

Comment: How would you implement `isBalanced()` without `getHeight()`?

Comment: @200_success yeah, thank you i realized the same think as you, that one node as child is acceptable :D